# Trying to reduce the size of boxes on screen

Tags: select, twitter-bootstrap-3, margin

I am trying to setup a style based on bootstrap3.

Basically I want to try and reduce the size of the input elements which I have done, getting a decent proportion of 'box' vs 'text'.
However if I use the same font-size in a select box with the same size then I get a situation where the text is masked along the bottom edge...

I think there is a tiny bit more margin at the top of the select box, but for the life of me I cant find where that is set in BootStrap to change it (if at all).

I think all I need to do is move the text in the 'select' element up by a couple of pixels and it will align with those bits of text in standard text boxes....

Can anyone point me in the right direct please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the associated CSS in the bootstrap, with a bit of trial and error....

Mainly in the 'form-control' section.

but now also using Bootstrap 4, with a couple of additional styles.